# How to reference images with different file extensions from XAML?

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We develop a Xamarin.Forms UI library where images are stored as PNGs for Android and as PDFs for iOS. For Android, the images are located in the Resources folder and for iOS, the images are located in an asset catalog. The file name for each image is the same between iOS and Android, but the file extension differs.

Inspecting the Assets.car using `xcrun --sdk iphoneos assetutil --info Assets.car` shows that the images are stored as PDFs and are not converted to PNGs at build time.

```
...
{
  "AssetType" : "Image",
  "BitsPerComponent" : 8,
  "ColorModel" : "RGB",
  "Colorspace" : "srgb",
  "Compression" : "deepmap2",
  "Encoding" : "ARGB",
  "Image Type" : "kCoreThemeOnePartScale",
  "Name" : "ic_cup_coffee",
  "NameIdentifier" : 54350,
  "Opaque" : false,
  "PixelHeight" : 24,
  "PixelWidth" : 24,
  "RenditionName" : "ic_cup_coffee.pdf",
  "Scale" : 1,
  "SHA1Digest" : "0999A4B02703DF4A5FC84AF67FEF220E560F79DD",
  "SizeOnDisk" : 334,
  "Template Mode" : "automatic"
}
...
```

To reference images from XAML we have a helper class that maps a class field to the file name excluding the file extension:

```
public static class Images
{
    public static readonly string Ic_cup_coffee = "ic_cup_coffee"; // value equals file name
    ...
}
```

Inside the XAML we use the x:Static markup extension:

```
<Image Source="{x:Static images:Images.Ic_cup_coffee}" />
```

The problem that we have with this approach is that **sometimes** the images are not being displayed in iOS apps that integrate the Xamarin.Forms UI library as a NuGet package. On Android we do not face any issues.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#local-images) states how to use a single image file across different platforms but not how to handle files with different file extensions used for the same image source.

How to reference images from XAML with different file extensions correctly? Is our approach to reference images a valid one?

Comment: Your static class just mapping your image file name, and the image it self must be stored in each Resource folder of each platform

Comment: In iOS , if the extensions for image is `png` , it can been ignored . However , it the image is end with `.jpg` , it is necessary to provide full file name in code behind .

Comment: Images are store as PDFs extension for iOS ? I'm not sure if PDFs extension are for images, you might need a PDF reader instead.

Comment: In my experian, yes we need to set full file name including the extension for `jpg` image

Comment: It seems that our problem is not the file extension but rather a [conflict between the Assets.car in the nuget and the Assets.car in the iOS app](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/34/34762/bug.html). Anyhow the Xamarin documentation is not clear about how to use PDFs and PNGs as resources for an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reference images with different file extensions from XAML like this:

```
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
        <OnPlatform.iOS><FileImageSource File="ic_cup_coffee.pdf"/></OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android><FileImageSource File="ic_cup_coffee.png"/></OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Anyhow, this does not solve our issue that the images are sometimes not visible. We stick with using `<Image Source="ic_cup_coffee"/>` and we will analyze if this [bug](https://xamarin.github.io/bugzilla-archives/34/34762/bug.html) is the root of the problem.